# How can I toggle the data content when clicked over anywhere in the block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a faq page which contains numerous questions bound as below.
The active class adds functionality of drop down content. The script used is:

```
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-toggle');

    toggles.forEach(toggle => {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
            toggle.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
        });
    })
```

Demo:

```js
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-toggle');

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        toggle.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
    });
})
```

```html
<div class="faq active">
    <h3 class="faq-title">
        Title
    </h3>
    <p class="faq-text">
        Answer
    </p>
    <button class="faq-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

The toggle function is applied to the button which adds active class and thus creates the drop-down menu.
I want to show drop-down content whenever I click anywhere on the card. Currently, the drop down part opens up only when the button is clicked. I tried adding faq-toggle class to the main div but it won't work. How do I achieve this?

Comment: your code works fine it will add/remove the active class when you click on that button. I guess some problems with you css code

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that the class is being applied to the button only. What I want to achieve, is toggle to show up wherever I click on card and not only on the button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could hep you. Tell me if it not fits you.

```js
const toggleFaq = evt => {
  const faq = evt.target.parentNode.querySelector('.faq-text');
  if(evt.target.classList.contains('faq-toggle')){
    faq.style.display = faq.style.display === "block" ?
    "none" : "block";
  } else {
    faq.style.display = "none";
  }
  evt.stopPropagation();  
}

const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-toggle, .faq');

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleFaq);
})
```

```css
.faq-text {
  display: none;
}

.faq {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq active">
  <h3 class="faq-title">
    Question
  </h3>
  <p class="faq-text">
    Answer
  </p>
  <button class="faq-toggle">
        TOGGLE
    </button>
</div>
<div class="faq active">
  <h3 class="faq-title">
    Question
  </h3>
  <p class="faq-text">
    Answer
  </p>
  <button class="faq-toggle">
        TOGGLE
    </button>
</div>
<div class="faq active">
  <h3 class="faq-title">
    Question
  </h3>
  <p class="faq-text">
    Answer
  </p>
  <button class="faq-toggle">
        TOGGLE
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To toggle the entire card instead of just targeting the button

The code below will toggle active class whether you click anywhere inside of it or the button itself

```
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.faq');

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggle.classList.toggle('active');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` to `create context` of this. And use add remove class to add and remove class.

```js
const faqs = document.querySelectorAll(".faq");
let toggleDiv = function (evt) {
  const isActive = this.classList.contains("active");
  /// reset all
  faqs.forEach((x) => {
    x.classList.remove("active");
  });
  if (!isActive) {
    this.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("active");
  }
};
faqs.forEach((faq) => {
  faq.addEventListener("click", toggleDiv.bind(faq));
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: azure;
}
div.active{
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
    <div class="faq">
      <h3 class="faq-title">
        Title
      </h3>
      <p class="faq-text">
        Answer
      </p>
      <button class="faq-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="faq">
      <h3 class="faq-title">
        Title
      </h3>
      <p class="faq-text">
        Answer
      </p>
      <button class="faq-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```